# updating tool from site in cmd

Tags: cmd, updates

so i have a simple batch tool

its url is `somesite.tool[version].zip`
eg: `somesite.tool1.9.zip`

and theres a file in the tool called version.
in this case it contains `1.9`
the tool.zip will have the file version in its main folder
also it has 7za.exe in main folder.

and theres another file 'somesite.version.txt'
Oh just a note, the file downloads instantly on just entering the url and pressing enter (dropbox)

```
start "somesite.version.txt"
set /p "newversion=<path\version.txt"
```

its the path which gives the prob i know nothing about the path.

What i wanna to do is add a feature update in the tool which will automatically do the following

```
> download the version.txt
> close the browser from which it was dowloaded (optional)
> check with the current version.txt
> if not same extract the new tool after deleting the previous one
```

i am stuck at comparing coz i dont know where the file is downloaded automatically.

thanks in advance for your efforts

Comment: Could you rephrase that? It's entirly unclear to me what you actually want to achieve and what problem you encountered.

Comment: simply put i want to download a file and compare it with another file, if they are not equal do something.  the problem is i dont know where the file gets downloaded

Comment: You're downloading this with your web-browser, right? If you aren't prompted for a download location, the browser will save the file in the download directory you configured.

Comment: i know where it downloads in MY computer. I am making a tool available for others and then i wouldnt know where it would download for them.

Comment: There is no generic way to autodetect the location of an arbitrary download unless you want to scan the entire filesystem for a known file name. Different users may use different browsers with different default and/or manual download locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer
using wget.exe i can download the file to the current directory
wget somesite.version.txt